# RShiny datatable with SelectInput (multiple = TRUE) does not display correct values

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I'm making an RShiny web app & Leaflet to show the location of photos taken over the course of several years. The user should be able to select a single or multiple dates to see where the photos were taken on the given day(s). I'm also displaying a data table, which I'll use in this example, because that sufficiently demonstrates the problem.

At the moment, when the user selects multiple dates, not all points for those dates are showing. The number varies depending on the days you select.

For example, 2019-04-04 has 26 points, 2019-03-29 has 2 points, but when I select both Day 1 and Day 2, it shows only 14 points. I'm not sure why this is happening.

I imagine it has something to do with the SelectInput showing dates that are in date format.

It could also have to do with making it reactive.

I don't know how to do either of the above^

df

```
data <- data.frame(SourceFile = c("IMG1.JPG", "IMG2.JPG", "IMG3.JPG", "IMG4.JPG", "IMG5.JPG"), Date = as.Date(c("2019-04-04", "2019-04-04", "2019-04-04", "2019-03-29", "2019-03-29")
```

UI:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  selectInput("DateRange",
              label = "Filter images by date", choices = data$Date, multiple = TRUE, selected = data$Date[1]),
  dataTableOutput("Table")
)
```

Server:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  #DataTable Output
  output$Table <- renderDataTable({
    data$Date <- format(data$Date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    data <- data %>%
      as.data.frame() %>%
      filter(Date == input$DateRange) %>%
      select("SourceFile", "Date")

  })
```

This isn't the perfect example...I'm not totally sure how that made up data will work out, but this is what is actually happening:  "For example, 2019-04-04 has 26 points, 2019-03-29 has 2 points, but when I select both Day 1 and Day 2, it shows only 14 points. I'm not sure why this is happening."

I've tried also displaying a single value rather than multiple. Then, the error says my date "character string is not in a standard unambiguous format."

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `%in%` instead of `==`. Also made some other changes that may be needed -

```
output$Table <- renderDataTable({
    data %>%
      as.data.frame() %>%
      filter(Date %in% input$DateRange) %>%
      mutate(Date = format(Date, '%Y-%m-%d')) %>%
      select("SourceFile", "Date")

  })
```

Comment: When I use %in%, no data comes up in my table at all.